# jquery quiz shows only first and last pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a quiz. There are 4 question and every question has 4 answers. The problem is that after the first question has loaded and you choose an answer and press the next button, then the last question loads instead of the second. How can I stop execution? Or what is wrong with the code?

Could you help me please?

Here is the code:

```
q1.toDOM();
    clickAnswer();

    $('.options').on('click', function() { 

        if (q1.check($(this).text()) === true) { // q1 check method's actual parameter (the answer which was selected by user), $(this).text()= answer
            $('.answer').append('<h2>Your answer is correct!<br>Rolling Stones was established in 1962.</h2>');
        } else {
            $('.answer').append('<h2>Your answer is incorrect!<br>Rolling Stones was established in 1962.</h2>');
        }
        $('.next-button').show();
    });

    $('.next-button').on('click', function() {

        console.log('question2');
        indicateStep();
        var q2 = questions[1]; //create the second question with the 0'th element of the Array
        q2.toDOM();
        clickAnswer();
        $('.options').on('click', function() {
            if (q2.check($(this).text()) === true) {
                $('.answer').append('<h2>Your answer is correct!<br>Jean-Paul "Bluey" is the singer of Incognito</h2>');
            } else {
                $('.answer').append('<h2>Your answer is incorrect!<br>Jean-Paul "Bluey" is the singer of Incognito</h2>');
            }
            $('.next-button').show();
        });
        event.preventDefault;
    });


    $('.next-button').on('click', function() {
        console.log('question3');
        indicateStep();
        var q3 = questions[2]; //create the second question with the 0'th element of the Array
        q3.toDOM();
        clickAnswer();
        $('.options').on('click', function() {
            if (q3.check($(this).text()) === true) {
                $('.answer').append('<h2>Your answer is correct!<br>Michael Jackson sold 42.4 million albűlbums from Thriller</h2>');
            } else {
                $('.answer').append('<h2>Your answer is incorrect!<br>Michael Jackson sold 42.4 million albűlbums from Thriller</h2>');
            }
            $('.next-button').show();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why not, start the execution after the button is pressed?

Comment: I think I'm trying the execution after pressing... Or am I wrong?

Comment: So there is first the click event and then the other part of the code

Comment: If you're executing it after the button press. Then its ok, but if you're trying to stop an event and then starting it. It would be vague.

Comment: could you show an example maybe? Sorry, I'm novice in javascript yet... Did you checked the code above?

Comment: I have posted an answer to the problem. Have a look! :)

Answer (score 0):

The error you're facing is in this part.

```
$('.next-button').on('click', function() {

    console.log('question2');
    indicateStep();
    var q2 = questions[1]; //create the second question with the 0'th element of the Array
    q2.toDOM();
    clickAnswer();
    $('.options').on('click', function() {
        if (q2.check($(this).text()) === true) {
            $('.answer').append('<h2>Your answer is correct!<br>Jean-Paul "Bluey" is the singer of Incognito</h2>');
        } else {
            $('.answer').append('<h2>Your answer is incorrect!<br>Jean-Paul "Bluey" is the singer of Incognito</h2>');
        }
        $('.next-button').show();
    });
    event.preventDefault;
});


$('.next-button').on('click', function() {
    console.log('question3');
    indicateStep();
    var q3 = questions[2]; //create the second question with the 0'th element of the Array
    q3.toDOM();
    clickAnswer();
    $('.options').on('click', function() {
        if (q3.check($(this).text()) === true) {
            $('.answer').append('<h2>Your answer is correct!<br>Michael Jackson sold 42.4 million albűlbums from Thriller</h2>');
        } else {
            $('.answer').append('<h2>Your answer is incorrect!<br>Michael Jackson sold 42.4 million albűlbums from Thriller</h2>');
        }
        $('.next-button').show();
    });
});
```

You're having 2 event handlers for this one element. Which would always move all the way down to the last event. Which I think is the event which would load the 4th question for the user. Here would be the example work

```
event triggered...

if answer correct
   load second question
if answer correct
   load third question
if answer corrent
   load fourth question
```

You're not having any condition to check, which question was submitted and which question load next. You should try this code instead, in the following code I would check for a condition using a class, you can change the condition to some other variable too. To check which question the user is currently working on.

```
$('.next-button').on('click', function() {
   if($(this).attr('class') == 'first-question') { // add condition
    console.log('question2');
    indicateStep();
    var q2 = questions[1]; //create the second question with the 0'th element of the Array
    q2.toDOM();
    clickAnswer();
    $('.options').on('click', function() {
        if (q2.check($(this).text()) === true) {
            $('.answer').append('<h2>Your answer is correct!<br>Jean-Paul "Bluey" is the singer of Incognito</h2>');
        } else {
            $('.answer').append('<h2>Your answer is incorrect!<br>Jean-Paul "Bluey" is the singer of Incognito</h2>');
        }
        $('.next-button').show();
    });
    event.preventDefault;
   } else if ($(this).attr('class') == 'second-question') { // another condition
      // code for second question...
   }
});
```

...and so on.

Secondly, just as a suggestion not an answer. It would be a good UX if you just add

> Correct answer || Wrong answer

Instead of

> Corrent answer, [name] is the singer for Incognito || Wrong answer, [name] never sung the Incognito.

Long errors or long triumph are not good! You should try to minimize them.

Comment: I see, thank you! The case is that I have to serve the next question in the case of good or wrong answer as well, but as I see your solution does this. How could I make this part of code more easier? I mean after I create the code for all the 4 questions then I'll have a very long code.

Comment: I think, long code would be required for this project! :) I won't stop just because code I'm about to write is lengthy. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve successive updates with binding different functions to the same event. At the moment a user clicks `.next-button` you should have an idea of which step was passed and which one to show next (based on some kind of condition).

I would suggest to have some kind of global variable like `window.current_question_id` which would indicate a current position (other possible options here are `css` classes and `data` attributes). Clicking `.next-button` would check the question number and show the next question (if any of them left).

Take a look at the [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yBN6D/) I've posted to get a basic idea of what should happen.

I would also incapsulate the right answer inside of your question objects (as you already do some kind of it when ask for `q3.check()`). This would let you not to repeat your code (as functions for `q2` and `q3` displaying look pretty similar).

```
# we can get rid of three functions for click event
# lets make the signle function responsible for that instead
$('.next-button').on('click', function() {
  # we should know which step we're at.
  # I assume you have window.current_question_id set up
  # and you handle the case of no more questions left by yourself here
  var next_question = questions[window.current_question_id + 1];
  next_question.toDOM();
  clickAnswer();
  $('.options').on('click', function() {
      # lets assume answer is incorrect by default. one less condition!
      var correctness = 'incorrect';
      if (next_question.check($(this).text()) === true) {
        correctness = 'correct';
      }
      var appending_text = '<h2> Your answer is ' + correctness + '!<br>';
      # I noticed you show pretty the same string here regardless of correctness.
      # why not to incapsulate it in your `q` objects so they just return that string?
      appending_text = appending_text + next_question.correct_answer();
      $('.answer').append(appending_text);
      $('.next-button').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: here I declare the questions:

Comment: so, the questions are in an array, and have the parameters: question, answers(in an array), and a good answer index

Comment: should I add a next parameter, which shows the index of the question?

Comment: @photoscene I'm not sure where does `question.check()` function comes from then. The idea is to have current question index at any point of code execution. The implementation of that index may vary (can't say more w/o looking at a full code).

Comment: @photoscene well, that is a bit too much. I've updated my answer with a js fiddle sample to give you a basic idea of question indexing and what your `$(.next-button).click()` function should look like. Give it a look: http://jsfiddle.net/yBN6D/